# Cannot detect wireless network after reboot

Tags: wireless

At first I could detect wireless networks, but after rebooting I can no longer activate the wireless card.

I can connect however to the internet via cable, wired connection but not wireless

**How do i detect and connect to my wireless network?**

Comment: What is the output of lspci

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [Ubuntu community wiki?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community)

There is a very good [wireless troubleshooting guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide) that I suggest to follow.